# How do I include a file over 2 directories back?

Tags: php, include, filesystems

How do you include a file that is more than 2 directories back. I know you can use `../index.php` to include a file that is 2 directories back, but how do you do it for 3 directories back?
Does this make sense?
I tried `.../index.php` but it isn't working.

I have a file in `/game/forum/files/index.php` and it uses PHP include to include a file. Which is located in `/includes/boot.inc.php`; `/` being the root directory.

Comment: chdir(''../'');

Answer (score 196):

`..` selects the parent directory from the current. Of course, this can be chained:

```
../../index.php
```

This would be two directories up.

Comment: @Brian Well, that’s nonsense, you’re comparing apples and oranges. You’re right that a `define` would be used here but (1) that wasn’t even remotely the question here. And (2) you’d still use a relative path in your `define`, Unless you actually hard-code the whole absolute server path and I would refrain from that since it has only disadvantages. Or (the third alternative) you could use string manipulation to extract parent directory from the (expanded) current path but once again this doesn’t have *any* advantages to using relative paths.

Comment: Sadly this may work on one device and not another, `/../` may work or `../` may work, or neither may work on three different computers with the exact same environment setup

Comment: @DouglasGaskell No, that’s incorrect. The relative path notation, including `../` and `../../` (note: **no** leading slash!), works on all modern operating systems. It *used to* not work on Windows and (*long* ago) Macintosh but it now works everywhere, and has for at least the last ten years. If it doesn’t work somewhere then the reason is that the file structure is different, and/or you’re in a different working directory. But it’s unrelated to this code.

Comment: Konrad, I mention this since I just dealt with this issue not 10 minutes ago after sharing a repository with a coworker, using a VM snapshot. For some reason all the paths had to have `/../` instead of `../` on his environment.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell And I can tell you with confidence that the error is unrelated. In fact, the path `/../` simply makes no sense on any system (it's equivalent to `/`, or an error). Are you sure you're not *pasting* something in front of it?

Answer (score 55):

To include a file one directory back, use `'../file'`.
For two directories back, use `'../../file'`.
And so on.

Although, realistically you shouldn't be performing includes relative to the current directory. What if you wanted to move that file?  All of the links would break.  A way to ensure that you can still link to other files, while retaining those links if you move your file, is:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'directory/directory/file');
```

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a server variable that represents the base directory that your code is located within.

Comment: Hey Dan quick question: you say "***realistically you shouldn't be performing includes relative to the current directory***". What about all the relative paths that are littered throughout most HTML documents? If I moved my file, wouldn't those break as well? Is there a standard of when to use relative vs absolute links? Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think its missing one slash , it should be : require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory/directory/file');

Comment: @user889030 as far as I know, that slash is not needed, at least in most of the cases

Comment: @BotMaster3000 hmmm : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66851aa1a964ae81d727c235fe416a3745b5e037

Answer (score 31):

```
. = current directory
.. = parent directory
```

**So `../` gets you *one directory back not two***.

Chain `../` as many times as necessary to go up 2 or more levels.

Answer (score 25):

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../index.php';
```

is your best bet here, and it will avoid most of the relative path bugs you can encounter with other solutions.

Indeed, it will force the include to always be **relative to the position of the current script** where this code is placed (which location is most likely stable, since you define the architecture of your application). This is different from just doing `include '../../index.php'` [which will include relatively to the executing (also named "calling") script and then relatively to the current working directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), which will point to the parent script that includes your script, instead of resolving from your included script's path.

From the PHP documentation:

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing.

And the oldest post I've found citing this trick [dates back to 2003, by Tapken](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php#21138).

You can test with the following setup:

Create a layout like this:

```
htdocs
¦   parent.php
¦   goal.php
¦
+---sub
    ¦   included.php
    ¦   goal.php
```

In `parent.php`, put:

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'/sub/included.php';
?>
```

In `sub/included.php`, put:

```
<?php
print("WRONG : " . realpath('goal.php'));
print("GOOD : " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/goal.php'));
?>
```

Result when accessing `parent.php`:

```
WRONG : X:\htdocs\goal.php
GOOD : X:\htdocs\sub\goal.php
```

As we can see, in the first case, the path is resolved from the calling script `parent.php`, while by using the `dirname(__FILE__).'/path'` trick, the include is done from the script `included.php` where the code is placed in.

Beware, the following NOT equivalent to the trick above contrary to what can be read elsewhere:

```
include '/../../index.php';
```

Indeed, prepending `/` will work, but it will resolve just like `include ../../index.php` from the calling script (the difference is that `include_path` won't be looked afterwards if it fails). [From PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
>   or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
>   current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be
>   ignored altogether.

Comment: @diEcho: may I know why it "is completely wrong"? I am using it on several professional-grades application and this method is actually the only one that worked in every situation. It's also detailed in the  [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): it can't be that wrong.

Comment: first line is completely wrong. You can not add `..` middle of the path (relative/absolute).

Comment: @diEcho I should also point you to the PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: tell me a single example, where `..` is used middle of the include. it always should be the first part of include

Comment: https://github.com/lrq3000/dolibarr_customfields/blob/3.2/htdocs/customfields/core/substitutions/functions_customfields.lib.php#L56 A professional-grade module for a professional-grade ERP/CRM.

You, sir, should not talk when you shan't know what you say.

Comment: @diEcho: also you should know that every include is automatically resolved since PHP 4.peanuts, in a way similar to what realpath() does.

Comment: at first I too thought @gaborous is wrong, but I tried! :-)

It works!

And, as i think, this should be the accepted answer, since this will help a lot in working local and live without hassle :-)

thanks gaborous

Comment: @DevTest You're welcome, and please excuse me for some of my somewhat angry comments above.

Answer (score 16):

```
../../index.php
```

Answer (score 16):

`../` is one directory, Repeat for two directories `../../` or even three: `../../../` and so on.

Defining constants may reduce confusion because you will drill forward into directories verses backwards

You could define some constants like so:

```
define('BD', '/home/user/public_html/example/');

define('HTMLBD', 'http://example.com/');
```

When using 'BD' or my 'base directory' it looks like so:

```
file(BD.'location/of/file.php');
```

[define(); reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 12):

```
../../../includes/boot.inc.php
```

Each instance of `../` means up/back one directory.

Answer (score 12):

***Try This***

**this example is one directory back**

```
require_once('../images/yourimg.png');
```

**this example is two directory back**

```
require_once('../../images/yourimg.png');
```

Comment: It's exactly the same ;-) I think you mean '../../images/yourimg.png' on the second one?

Comment: opps  its my mistake

Answer (score 10):

if you are using php7 you can use dirname function with level parameter of 2, for example :

```
dirname("/usr/local/lib", 2);
```

the second parameter "2" indicate how many level up

[dirname referance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Answer (score 9):

following are ways to access your different directories:-

```
./ = Your current directory
../ = One directory lower
../../ = Two directories lower
../../../ = Three directories lower
```

Answer (score 8):

I recomend to use `__DIR__` to specify [current php file directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398508/6521116). Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43917238/6521116) for the reason.

```
__DIR__ . /../../index.php
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do `../../directory/file.txt` -  This goes two directories back.

`../../../` - this goes  three. etc

Answer (score 7):

```
../../../index.php
```

Answer (score 7):

But be ***VERY*** careful about letting a user select the file.  You don't really want to allow them to get a file called, for example,

```
../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

or other sensitive system files.

(Sorry, it's been a while since I was a linux sysadmin, and I *think* this is a sensitive file, from what I remember)

Answer (score 5):

```
../../../includes/boot.inc.php
```

Answer (score 3):

including over directories can be processed by proxy file

- root
- .....|__web
- .....|.........|_requiredDbSettings.php
- .....|
- .....|___db
- .....|.........|_dbsettings.php
- .....|
- .....|_proxy.php

  ```
  dbsettings.php:
  $host='localhost';
  $user='username':
  $pass='pass';

  proxy.php:
  include_once 'db/dbsettings.php

  requiredDbSettings.php:
  include_once './../proxy.php';
  ```

Answer (score 2):

if you include the `/` at the start of the include, the include will be taken as the path from the root of the site.

if your site is http://www.example.com/game/forum/files/index.php you can add an include to /includes/boot.inc.php which would resolve to http://www.example.com/includes/boot.inc.php .

You have to be careful with `..` traversal as some web servers have it disabled; it also causes problems when you want to move your site to a new machine/host and the structure is a little different.

Answer (score 2):

I saw your answers and I used include path with syntax

```
require_once '../file.php'; // server internal error 500
```

and http server (Apache 2.4.3) returned internal error 500.

When I changed the path to

```
require_once '/../file.php'; // OK
```

everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try `../../`. You can modify it accordingly as it will take you up back two directories. First reach to root directory then access the required directory.

E.g. You are in `root/inc/usr/ap` and there is another directory `root/2nd/path`. You can access the `path` directory from `ap` like this: 
`../../2nd/path` first go to root than desired directory. If not working please share.