# Why doesnt ../ (dot dot slash) work in my root directory?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relative include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398451/relative-include-files)

For example,

```
    include('../admin/db_cred.php');
```

That works if I am in another folder such as public. However if I am just at www.SITE.com/index.php, it does not work.

Warning: include(../admin/db_cred.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[...].php on line 6

I added the (dot dot slash) because searching ../ does not work very well...

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: Sorry, I updated to include the warning.

Comment: @KeithThompson `"does not work very well"`

Comment: Make your path absolute.

Comment: You don't have permission to access that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `../` convention indicates to move up one directory level from where you are. If you are in the root directory, you cannot move up any more levels.

If your /admin folder is in the root directory and you call this from the /public directory, then `../admin/` would allow you to select the /admin folder from one level below

Answer (score 2):

`../` means "the folder above this one" or "move up a folder." For example, if you are in a terminal and enter `cd ../` you will move up a folder from where you started.

When you're at `site.com/index`, you are very likely in the web root of your site and, therefore, cannot go up a level, because there is no level up.

"But there are folders above `/var/www`!" Yes, there are, but your scripts do not have access to them (this is a very good thing, you don't want a hijacked script to gain access to your entire server). As far as your scripts are concerned, `/var/www` (or whatever your web root is) *is* the topmost level, regardless of what is actually on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

../ is parent folder, but root have no parent.

If you want to resolve

```
http://site/admin/db_cred.php
```

you should write it like this:

```
include('~/admin/db_cred.php');
```