# What does ".\" mean in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

In the context of `The directory where your SQL scripts are. Defaults to .\` does `.\` represent the directory you are currently in?

What about `..\`?

What about `SET DIR=%~d0%~p0%`

Comment: What is the full context?  Is that on a line by itself? or preceding a command?  How is it used?

Comment: `.` is current directory. `..` is parent directory. You can also append the backslash. In context, with a following path or name, of course you need the backslash (e.g., `..\foo`).

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Sam yes, either, really. The `.` and `..` are the directory names, but you can also refer to them as ".\" and "..\".

Comment: @ Sam See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "./" (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398451/relative-include-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921252/why-doesnt-dot-dot-slash-work-in-my-root-directory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash. Google `dot dot slash` for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does .\ represent the directory you are currently in?

Yes.

> What about ..\?

The parent directory

> What about `SET DIR=%~d0%~p0%`

[MS docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Set the environment variable DIR to the drive and path of the batch file.