# PHP - include in subdir not working

Tags: php, directory, include, include-path, subdirectory

This is what I have

```
site.com/user/filehere.php
```

I need to go to

```
site.com/user/messages/index.php
```

the index.php is

```
<?php 
include_once("../filehere.php");
?>
```

The problem is that inside `filehere.php`

there is another includes like

filehere.php

```
<?php  

include_once("../menu.php); 

?>
```

and these includes are not reconized in the /messages dir even when it's all ok when I acess directly the included file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398508/6521116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add **`__DIR__`** to your file path to represent the current php dir. For more refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398508/6521116).

Comment: same problem with subdir it shows the page ok but the includes in the page are not displayed

Comment: Today I also encountered this, I solve it by specify the absolute path.  For example, I use laravel, I use <code>app_path() . '/services/aaa.php'</code>

Comment: I am making this in pure php so I will have to change all includes in the site

Comment: May be you can wrote a simple autoloader for your php files, which will save a great work. May be there are other include way. Wait for some expert to answer it.

Comment: I think I will change one by one with `include_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site/user/file.php');` I will see what I will implement