# Find css file using nodejs

Tags: html, structure, filepath

This is my structure

[image]

**I'm trying to load the main.css file from the header.ejs file, can't find it.**

This code is in my header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello and wellcome to my album</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/main.css">

    </head>
    <body>
```

Comment: try `../../public/`

Comment: tried '../../public/stylesheets/main.css' not working

Comment: try commenting the first one and check if the problem is not in the first link tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a file over 2 directories back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162873/how-do-i-include-a-file-over-2-directories-back)

Comment: I imagine that this is a nodejs app....did you set the public folder as `static`? open your devtools and check if there are errors in your console

Comment: if you have any update it will be nice to post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in app.js i added:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

in the header.ejs i changed:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
```

*i am using NodeJS*

Answer (score 3):

Try to go 2 directories back, not 1.

Like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Link should be like below cause you have 2 sub folder back then you will get public folder and stylesheets

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/main.css">
```

`..` selects the parent directory from the current.

(..) 2 times because first, you need to go 2 directories back and then go to public and then stylesheet and then main.css

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your stylesheet path is set wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
<head>
    <title>Hello and wellcome to my album</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
```

You are pointing just a folder up from partials to views. You need anothe folder up to your site root dir just like I pointed. Generally you could just use `/public/stylesheets/main.css` which is directly pointing to project root folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a nodejs app, path should be like following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

If your path static:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
```